# Prevent modal from closing when submiting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form inside a modal, I want to prevent the modal from closing and refreshing the page after submiting the form if there's errors on some fields and show error messages inside the modal, if everything is okay the modal shoud submit the form and refresh the page.

This is my code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addTeam">
<div class="modal-dialog rap-modal-thumb">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add team</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><br>
              <div class="page-wrap">
                <form action= "<?php echo $action; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                  <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">                                                   
                          <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                              <div class="col-third input-group-icon">
                                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nom*" required="required">
                                <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-third input-group-icon">
                                <input type="text" id="abreviation" name="abreviation" placeholder="Abréviation*" required="required">
                                <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i></div>
                                </div>
                        <br>
                        * Required fields
                        <br><br>
                        <?php
                            if (isset($error)) 
                                echo '<div style="color:#fff;" class="alert bg-danger" role="alert"><em class="fa fa-lg fa-warning">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em>',$erreur,'</div>';  
                        ?>
                        <button type="submit" id="addTeam" name="addTeam" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In php if for example the name of the team is less than 6 characters then show the error message inside the modal without closing it. In my case here the message appear after the page is refreshed and the show button of the modal is clicked again.

```
if (isset($_POST['addTeam'])) {
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    if (strlen($name)<3){
        $error = 'Name must be atleast 6 characters';
    }
    else{
        $action = "uploadTeam.php";
    }
}
```

Anyway to do that ?

Comment: You need to use an `AJAX` call for that

Comment: Any useful links or codes to follow ?

Comment: Here is a link to get help with AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Change your code with these snippets and come back with your code updated to get more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your form is submited by default by the browser, it'll auto-refresh the page (to create a new HTTP POST request to the server)

You have to use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to call the server on background and avoid reloading the content:

```
// Create an event listener to catch "when the form is submited"
$('.modal-body form').submit(function(event) {
    // to stop the form from submitting (and the page reloading, so the modal will not close)
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // Call server manually and send form data (see Mikey's comment)
    $.post('my.url.com/file.php', $(this).serialize(), function(err, result) {
      if (err) { 
        // Display error on form 
      } else {
        // Success... Redirect ?
        window.location = 'my.new.url/path.html'
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Good idea to replace `{data: {foo:bar}}` with `$(this).serialize()` in order to pass your form's data (`this` is your native form element and `$(this)` is the form as a jQuery object).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override some client behavior for this. In fact, it will be easier for you to do your validation all on the client side (if possible). Override the form's default behavior, validate, and then return `true` or `false` based on the results of your validation function:

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        if (validate()) { //your validation function here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    function validate() {
        if (!$('input[name=name]').val() || $('input[name=name]').val().length < 3) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're avoiding the submit, But this will not create a request to the server, it's only a part of the answer.

Comment: @Arthur, it will, if the validation passes. Returning `true` from this event will cause the submission of the form to continue.

Comment: But he'll not be able to call server to test his form like that.

Comment: Hmmm, good point. I didn't realize he is doing server-side validation.

Comment: Also you can write it like that `$('form').on('submit', validate)` instead of creating a delta function.